# Why is my range selector not working in my Google Maps API3 / jQuery Mobile App?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-mobile

I want to vary the radius of a circle made in Google Maps API3 based on a jQuery Mobile range selector:

http://goo.gl/T1OHC

However, Chrome Web Developer keeps issuing the error "Uncaught Error: Invalid value for property : _" every time I alter my slider. Why?

Comment: It does?  Latest version of Chrome on Windows 7 64 bit, Mac OS X 10.7.3 and Fedora 15 all have your example running and no errors in JavaScript console in dev tools.

Comment: Oh, I am sorry. I had just fixed it two hours ago. The problem was that Google Maps API3 was parsing `$(this).val()` as a string, whereas an integer value was needed. To solve this issue, I replaced `$(this).val()` with `parseInt($(this).val())`. The Devil's in the details in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved my own problem. The problem was that Google Maps API3 was parsing `$(this).val()` as a string, whereas an integer value was needed. To solve this issue, I replaced `$(this).val()` with `parseInt($(this).val())`.

Here is my final javascript.

```
$('input#circleRadius').change(function() {
    circle.setRadius(parseInt($(this).val()));
    });
});
```